# Selecting FPC connector for LCD

Tags: connector, ffc, fpc

The flexible flat cable of the LCD i want to use has these odd ground pads in the ends that i have not seen before. How is this handled in practise, does it turn the otherwise 37 pin connector into a 41 pin connector to account for the extra padding, appearing like approximately two extra pads in each of the ends or does this require some special connector/treatment?

It looks like a special locking feature for the connector is needed. Is there a name for this ?

[image: Odd FFC]

Comment: These are for holding the connector in place and connect to the chassis/protective earth, if you have one.

Comment: I assume you mean for holding the flat cable in place, not the connector. Are special connectors needed for this, if so what is the term for this mechanism/feature ?

Comment: No. The connector. It is soldered to PCB, so it holds it on it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. this is a drawing of the flex ribbon, not the connector PCB footprint.  In terms of what connector would match, it would really help to have an actual picture.  If this is just copper and possible a perforation on the ribbon, it is possible that a connector with a higher pin count would work, where it looks like several contacts on each end would get this ground.  But it may also be metal capture features crimped over the ribbon, which need to mate with something matching in the connector.    A photo would help differentiate.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Is it? How can it be deduced? Stonie, please make it clearer in the question.

Comment: @EugeneSh. That is it is a ribbon and not a connector footprint is evident from the geometry of the drawing, complete difference from a connector footprint drawing, and experience with these parts - and also the present text of the question - they are asking to *find* a connector, not how to create a *footprint* from a connector data sheet.

Comment: @Stonie Please link to the datasheet for your LCD that contains this FFC drawing